Postgres: Split array elements into columns
I'm new to postgres and I have a requirement wherein I need to split an array of integers into individual elements (as columns) for the application to consume it.
Consider this for example:
create table employees(age int, name text, scores int[]);
insert into employees values(25, 'Name1', ARRAY [10, 20, 30]);
insert into employees values(48, 'Name2', ARRAY [40, 50 , 60, 70]);
select scores[1], scores[2], scores[3] from employees where age > 40 and age < 50;

The select statement returns the output as:
scores | scores | scores
-------------------------
  40   |   50   |   60

For accessing the elements of a large array, the above select statement will grow in size accordingly, and it is not generic enough for different array sizes. Can we have a query to do this elegantly regardless of the array size?
Thanks in advance!

You will need dynamic SQL for that, and you'll need to use it indirectly (2-step calls). PostgreSQL needs to be able to determine the number, names and types of output columns at the start of the query. You can't have a function or a statement that's able to return different types and amounts of fields under different names at different times, completely dynamically. However, you can have a routine that dynamically constructs the query and dumps its contents to a table, which you can then read from in the second step. You can also just offload this to front end, where it's usually trivial.

Question is, why do you want each array element in a separate column? You can select * from employees cross join unnest(scores) with ordinality as u(score,score_number); and get each score in a separate row rather than column, with score_number indicating what position in the array it came from.

The existing scheme of things is that 'select' is accessing every index of the array in order the fetch the values in the array, in the database query. So my intent was to fetch the contents of the array in a loop or the equivalent, rather than hand-code every index of the array.

About having a separate column for each element, that stemmed from how the output was formatted in my question above. It's not really a requirement.

How do you consume the result in your application? Maybe another solution would be to modify that application to be able to handle the arrays. What are you using to hold the data you read? An ORM, query-builder, pandas, excel, ...?

Question is, why do you want each array element in a separate column? You can get each score in a separate row rather than column, with score_number indicating what position in the array it came from. Demo at db<>fiddle:
select * from employees
  cross join unnest(scores) with ordinality as u(score,score_number);




age
name
scores
score
score_number




25
Name1
{10,20,30}
10
1


25
Name1
{10,20,30}
20
2


25
Name1
{10,20,30}
30
3


48
Name2
{40,50,60,70}
40
1


48
Name2
{40,50,60,70}
50
2


48
Name2
{40,50,60,70}
60
3


48
Name2
{40,50,60,70}
70
4



Otherwise, you will need dynamic SQL execute for that, and you'll need to use it indirectly (2-step calls). PostgreSQL needs to be able to determine the number, names and types of output columns at the start of the query. You can't have a function or a statement that's able to return different types and amounts of fields under different names at different times, completely dynamically.
However, you can have a routine that dynamically constructs the query using format(), then executes and dumps its result to a table, which you can then read from in the second step.
It side-steps the limitation because you're constantly returning a text with the name of the table where the real result is being dumped to. The side effects of the routine aren't restricted the way its direct output is.
create function f_employee_scores_into_columns(employee_name text)returns text
language plpgsql as $f$
declare rec record;
        first_score_number int;
        last_score_number int;
        query_body text;
begin
  --check how many elements there are in the target array
  select array_lower(scores,1)
        ,array_upper(scores,1)
  from employees
  where employees.name=employee_name
  limit 1
  into first_score_number
      ,last_score_number;
  --construct a column list, placing each element in separate column
  select string_agg(format('scores[%1$s] as "score_%1$s"',score_number)
                    ,',' order by score_number)
  from generate_series(first_score_number,last_score_number,1)score_number
  into query_body;
  --inject the constructed column list into the final query
  --then execute it, writing the result to a table
  execute format('drop table if exists output_f_employee_scores_into_columns;
                  create table output_f_employee_scores_into_columns as
                  select age,name,%s 
                  from employees 
                  where employees.name=$1',query_body) using employee_name;
    
  --you would want to randomise the output table name and make it temp
  --right now all calls in all sessions would overwrite each other's outputs
  return 'output_f_employee_scores_into_columns';
end $f$;

--2-step call
select f_employee_scores_into_columns('Name2');
select * from output_f_employee_scores_into_columns;




age
name
score_1
score_2
score_3
score_4




48
Name2
40
50
60
70



--2-step call
select f_employee_scores_into_columns('Name1');
select * from output_f_employee_scores_into_columns;




age
name
score_1
score_2
score_3




25
Name1
10
20
30



You can also just offload this to front end, where it's usually trivial.

Thanks for your suggestion! Please allow me sometime to deliberate on this. I shall get back to you.
